# Angular 2+ accessing class variables from event (ag grid)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, class

I'm trying to create a button that would edit a class' boolean to true upon being clicked. The code looks like this:

```
export class componentName{

    public editingMode = false;
    private colDefinitions = [
    {
        headername: "Edit",
        field: "edit",
        cellRenderer: this.editCellRendererFunc
    }];


    editCellRendererFunc(params){
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Need to modify editingMode from here.
        }
    }

    constructor(private _svc:GridHTTP){
            this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
            this.gridOptions = {
                enableFilter: true,
                columnDefs: this.colDefinitions
            }
    }
```

I understand that I can't access the pointer anymore. Is there any method of having this variable be accessible so I can use an *ngIf in the template.html in order to hide/show DOM elements whenever that button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ag grid allows for custom parameters apparently, doing as follows allows access to the class scope:

```
            // under columnDefs
            {
                headerName: "Edit",
                field: "edit",
                cellRenderer: this.editCellRendererFunc,
                cellRendererParams: {
                    _self: this;
                }
            }

    // Later in the code
     editCellRendererFunc(params) {
          params._self.changeEditingMode(true);    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

usually what i do if a want to have a EDITABLE TABLE (or smilar) is like this:

1 - create a edit : boolean field in your model ... so for example:

```
export class Use{

public id: number;
public name:string;
 // ... other prop
public edit: boolean //put this .. maybe you can have in a entitybase and then extends ALL your models from tit
}
```

2 - in your HTML:

```
<table>


 <th>ID</th>
 <th>NAME</th>
 <th> OTHER </th>

 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows" (click)="editable(row)">
    <td *ngIf="!row.edit" [innerText]="row.id"></td>
    <td *ngIf="row.edit"><input type="number" step="1" [(ngModel)]="row.id" /> </td>
    <td *ngIf="!row.edit" [innerText]="row.name"></td>
    <td *ngIf="row.edit"><input type="text"[(ngModel)]="row.name" /> </td>
    <td *ngIf=""><input type="number" step="1" [(ngModel)]="row.id" /> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3- in your ts file (component)

```
editable(item : User){

//first make all edit=false
this.rows.foreach(xx=>xx.edit=false);

//then set edit=true the clicked row
row.edit=true;

}
```

..matìybe then you have to make a directive to make all rows.edit=false when YOU CLICK OUTSIDE the table (you can find some example on stackoverflow)

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: The main issue with this entire scenario is that I do not want to use a regular table but instead an ag grid table (for consistency purposes with other components). This means that the only way to fix it would be to somehow access the variable from outside of its original scope.

Is a global variable my only option?

Comment: but sorry .. if you use ag-grid (i didn't read it sorry) ... it has a edit mode .. doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but I'm trying to show a specific tab whenever the buttons in the grid are clicked, and then tab out to that tab. So I'm forced (afaik) to use *ngIf and a boolean, which in this case is editingMode, which then transfers the user to a specific form designated for a sort of "final modification".

Comment: ok .. so yes you can use a global var OR a broadcasting and a listener with a  event submitter

Comment: Isn't it a waste though since I only need the variable across a single component, not through multiple components?

Comment: yep if it's in the same compoent you can use a private bool field i think

Comment: How do I access that bool? I can't use this.varName since the scope is screwed.

Comment: can you mark in your cide where is lost your scope?? can you try to wrap your this in a var _self .. before it?

Comment: I've already added that bool as you can see in my code, the issue is the scope's screwed.
I'm assuming it lost the scope because this current clicking event is set at the cell rendering function, so it is called with specific parameters that do not include "this" pointer.